# Including libraries in the custom code section in Simulink

Tags: c, matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I'm trying to Include some Libraries, like `metis` in the custom code library section in Simulink. Do you know what type of libraries Simulink excepts? Must they have the ending `.a`, `.o`, `.dll` or `lib`?
 And can I include them into my custom c code with `#include <metis.h>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library format should match the architecture on which you are going to compile the generated code. So `.a` or `.so` for GNU/Linux, `.lib` for Windows (you usually link against the `.lib` file not the `.dll`), and usually `.dylib` on Mac. You can also link in object files, (i.e. `.o, .obj`) but typically a software package will build some type of library for you to use.

If you are using any of the functions, types, etc. defined in any of the `metis` headers, then those headers need to be included in the generated code.

You can add `#include "header_name.h"` to the settings:

```
"Configuration Parameters->Simulation Target->Custom Code->Header File"
```

and:

```
"Configuration Parameters->Code Generation->Custom Code->Header File"
```

where `header_name.h` is replaced with the needed header file's name.

Since this question is tagged `MATLAB Coder` you can also use `coder.cinclude('header_name.h');` in your MATLAB code to generate a `#include "header_name.h"` in the C code.

You may also need to augment the `Include directories` settings on the aforementioned `Custom Code` panes to allow the compiler to locate the headers.